# How can I change my username?

Tags: terminal

My current username is `mpatil`, how can I change that to `algo` without losing data or causing problems?

Comment: Are you trying to change your username or just your prompt?

Comment: @ John to change user name

Comment: On your system you are mpatil. You can change your name, set the system name (so localhost (the default) changes). Or just change the prompt `PS1="hello>"`

Comment: @richard see my update

Comment: @ram I completely rewrote your question so that it is clearer, my apologies if that is not what you were asking. Please [edit] your question and add the operating system you are using. Are you on Linux, OSX, BSD? Which version?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your login name with [`usermod`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod) by issuing the command (as root, or with `sudo`):

```
usermod --login algo mpatil
```

where `algo` is the new login name, and `mpatil` is the old login name.

This is roughly equivalent to [John's suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/101927/43779) of editing your `/etc/password` by hand, but less error prone, as `usermod` does the changes for you.

Note that this will *only* change your login name, in particular your home directory will not be changed to reflect your new login name (most likely it will still be `/home/mpatil`).

If you want to change your home directory as well, you can issue the command:

```
usermod --login algo --home /home/algo --move-home mpatil
```

This *can cause problems* with applications that record your login name or expanded home directory path in their configuration. You *will* have to configure the application that do this to use the new home directory path and/or login name yourself, the exact method depending of the application.

A good starting point to identify such application is to [`grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) for you old login / old home directory path in your [dotfiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotfile).

Answer (score 0):

mpatil is not the system name in `[mpatil@localhost ~]$` - it's the username (the system name is localhost). If you want it to say `algo` here, then log in as algo.

Comment: how to change system name?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your username, you must edit `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` as root, changing 'mpatil' to 'algo', then log out completely and log back in as 'algo'. If you want to switch to the pre-existing 'algo' account, use `su` or `sudo`.

Comment: `[root@localhost mpatil]# /etc/passwd
bash: /etc/passwd: Permission denied`

Comment: my question is just how to rename the mpatil to algo

Comment: You must edit those files. Don't try to run them, they're not scripts.

Comment: see my update..

Comment: A utility (such as `usermod -l`) will be much safer than editing `passwd` and `shadow` directly, especially for someone not familiar with them.

Comment: @John This isn't sufficient. You must also rename the home directory, user cron tabs, user mail boxes, etc.

Comment: Actually, you don't have to rename the home directory. You can leave it as 'mpatil'. But yeah, you will need to look at these other things - but even the `usermod` utility @Patrick mentioned won't handle those other items.

Comment: @John you don't have to rename the home directory, true. But that's the kind of cruft that I'd fully expect to come back to bite me later. Personally, I'd probably move it and put a symlink under the old name.

Comment: Oh, I expect a lot more than just that to come back to bite me in the butt. That's why I don't rename user accounts, I delete and create new after copying required data somewhere else. :)